# Why can bash cd to //?

Tags: bash, shell

In bash if you cd to // your pwd will be //, but if you cd to / or ///+ your pwd will be /. Is there a reason for this or is it just a weird bug?

I have tried this in osx and ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Bash FAQ](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ):

> E10) Why does `cd //' leave $PWD as `//'?
>
> POSIX.2, in its description of `cd', says that *three* or more leading
>   slashes may be replaced with a single slash when canonicalizing the
>   current working directory.
>
> This is, I presume, for historical compatibility.  Certain versions of
>   Unix, and early network file systems, used paths of the form
>   //hostname/path to access `path' on server `hostname'.

Comment: cool I though it was a bug... :)

Comment: Note Windows *still* uses // for network paths, so this may be a SMB compatibility thing too.

Comment: Technically, Windows uses \\ for UNC paths.

Answer (score 0):

Though the answer was correct on the data it gave, it didn't quite answer the question asked.

The shell is normalizing the path.  It does:

- change any part1/part2/.. components to part1/
- change any //+ components to /

You can verify this with strace, which will see what is actually passed into the syscall

```
strace -o /tmp/strace.out bash -c "cd ///tmp"
grep chdir /tmp/strace.out
# will give chdir("/tmp")

strace -o /tmp/strace.out bash -c "cd ///tmp/../etc"
grep chdir /tmp/strace.out
# will give chdir("/etc")
```

The shell does the path normalization before it even tells the system to change the dir